# Visual Basic Webbrowser to Textbox

Tags: vb.net, textbox, browser

Is there anyway I can insert a Web Browser in visual basic, and then define an area on a website where if something is typed in, that string will be transferred to a TextBox.

Comment: I can hack together some example code, but not in VB.Net, but in C# - is that a problem?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve at the end of this? That might help to understand your problem

Comment: I want to be able to add text to a textbox inside of a webbrowser, from my program.

Answer (score 0):

Your could use [watir](http://watir.com/) to do do some automation of the IE browser control, which you can add to your application.